# Dropwizard protobuf validation

Tags: java, jersey, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard and have a service that supports both json and protobuf. I really like the @Valid notation and annotation on fields inside my request classes. Problem is that the @Valid notation only works for json and not protobuf. Is there a way or a good approach for how to get the @Valid annotation to work regardless of the media-type?

Example service:

```
@POST
@Produces({
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/x-protobuf"
})
@Consumes({
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "application/x-protobuf"
})
@Path("/foo")
void foo(@Valid Request request);

public class Request
{
  @NotBlank(message = "Missing info")
  String field;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validations in Dropwizard before version 1.0.0 were done in the `JacksonMessageBodyProvider` class which is essentially a `MessageBodyReader` (class responsible for deserializing your POJOs).

As the name **Jackson** in the class depicts, this feature was probably meant to only work with JSON based entities.

Having said that, the only alternative is to perform the validations yourself in the resource method by writing this piece of code,

```
Validator validator = environment.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> violations = validator.validate(object, validationGroups);
```

Iterate the violations Set to identify all the violations in the request POJO, which can be sent out in the payload when you return the HTTP 4xx error response.

Since 1.0.0, going by this [Pull Request](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/pull/1251) on Github. Moving the validation logic out of Jackson to Jersey should essentially allow other entity types to make use of the feature. The `DropwizardConfiguredValidator` implementation is registered as a `ConfiguredValidator` in Jersey which performs the required validations.